# How do I pass data through a react route

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I need this route to pass some more data to the CreateRoom component Can someone help me with the syntax

```
<Route path="/" component={CreateRoom} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution using hooks in this case would be passing the state from wherever you link towards the Route specified above and using the useLocation hook inside the CreateRoom component to access the state.

However you will need to pass the prop from every place you link towards this route if you want to access it.

eg.:

```
<Link to={{pathname: "/", state = data }} />
```

Or using history.push:

```
const RandomComponent = (props) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const forwardToPage = () => {
        history.push({ pathname: "/", state: data})
    }
}
```

And in your CreateRoom component:

```
const CreateRoom = (props) => {
   const location = useLocation(); //This is imported from react-router-dom
   
   const data = location?.state;

   return(...)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Link` to send it

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/CreateRoom", state: data }} >
```

and then receive it with

```
 props.location.state
```

Comment: This is my CreateRoom component without the top portion (imports) In between the assignment of id and window.open I need to send the conversation recipients the link shown in window.open(...) ```const CreateRoom = (props) => {
    function create() {
        const id = uuid();
        
        window.open(`/room/${id}`, '_blank');
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={create}>Video chat</button>
    );
};

export default CreateRoom;
```

Comment: This is rendering into a page in a rails app

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass data using history and access it on that component.

```
props.history.push({
         pathname:"/CreateRoom",
         state:{
             userId:"1"
             ...
          }
 });
```

You can access like `props.location.state.userId`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use :

```
<Route path="/" >
  <CreateRoom data={your data} />
</Route
```

Or use the `Link` :

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/", state: data }} >
```

and then receive it in your `CreateRoom` with

```
const location = useLocation(); 
const data = location?.state;
```

Comment: If I use the first method I need to receive "data" not  state

Comment: Yes, of course ..., use `props.data` in your `CreateRoom` component